# how to leave only those days that are specified in JSON?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Actual behaviour Now a series of all days of the week is being built on the X-axis. like now: 2022-5-30 2022-5-31 2022-6-1 2022-6-2 2022-6-3 2022-6-4 2022-6-5 2022-6-6

Live demo with steps to reproduce
https://jsfiddle.net/5z1b9xnp/

```js
let globalData = []; let finRez = [];
let chart;

let duration = 500; // Determines how long the animation between new points should be take
let startIterator = 1; // Determines how many points will be rendered on chart's init
let currentIterator = startIterator;
let maxIterator = 1;

let guiButton = document.getElementById('start');
let guiButtonState = 'Start';
let intervalId;

// Fetch data:
fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/veleg/trade/main/trade.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    parseData(data);
    createChart();
    initEvents();
  });

function initEvents() {
  guiButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (guiButtonState === 'Stop') {
      // User clicked "Stop" -> stop animation and allow to resume
      intervalId = clearInterval(intervalId);
      guiButton.innerText = guiButtonState = 'Resume';
    } else {
      // If animation has finished, recreate chart
      if (guiButtonState === 'Restart') {
        createChart();
      }
      guiButton.innerText = guiButtonState = 'Stop';
      // Start animation:
      redrawChart(currentIterator += 1);
      intervalId = setInterval(function() {
        // If we reached last available point, stop animation:
        if (currentIterator === maxIterator) {
          intervalId = clearInterval(intervalId);
          currentIterator = startIterator;
          guiButton.innerText = guiButtonState = 'Restart';
        } else {
          redrawChart(currentIterator += 1);
        }
      }, duration);
    }
  });
}

function redrawChart(index) {
  // Set new subtitle on every redraw
  chart.setTitle(null, {
    text:  ' Заработано: ' + globalData[0].data[index][1]
  }, false);
    
    
    const newValues = globalData.map(series => series.data[index][1]);
    const maxIndex = newValues.indexOf(Math.max.apply(null, newValues));

  // To each series, add a point:
  chart.series.forEach(
    (series, seriesIndex) => {
            const enabled = maxIndex === seriesIndex && ((index < 5) || (index % 5 === 0));
      series.addPoint(
                {
          x: globalData[seriesIndex].data[index][0],
          y: globalData[seriesIndex].data[index][1]
                    <!-- dataLabels: { -->
                        <!-- enabled -->
                    <!-- }, -->
                    <!-- marker: { -->
                        <!-- enabled -->
                    <!-- } -->
        },
        false,
        false,
        false
      );
    }
  );

  // Now, once everything is updated, redraw chart:
  chart.redraw({
    duration
  });
}

function parseData(data) {
  Highcharts.objectEach(
    data,
    // Prepare Highcharts data-format:
    // series: [{
    //   data: [ [x, y], [x, y], ..., [x, y]]
    // }]
    (countryData, country) => {
            if (country !== 'Diamond Princess' && country !== 'Holy See') {
                globalData.push({
                    name: country,
                    data: countryData.map(p => [Date.parse(p.date), p.recovered / getCountryPopulation(country)])
                    <!-- data: countryData.map(p => [p.date, p.recovered / getCountryPopulation(country)]), -->
                    <!-- datas: countryData.date, -->
                    <!-- datass: countryData.map(p => [p.date, p.date]) -->
                });
            }       
            
        }
  );


  // Sort and limit dataset:
  globalData = globalData
    .sort((countryA, countryB) => {
      let countryALen,
        countryBLen;

      if (!countryA || !countryA.data || countryA.data.length === 0) {
        return 1;
      }

      if (!countryB || !countryB.data || countryB.data.length === 0) {
        return -1;
      }

      return countryB.data[countryB.data.length - 1][1] - countryA.data[countryA.data.length - 1][1];
    })
    .splice(0, 8);
        

  maxIterator = Math.max.apply(null, globalData.map(series => series.data.length - 1));
}


function createChart() {
    function format(y) {
    return y.toFixed(2);
  }

  chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
      type: 'spline',
      marginLeft: 100
    },

    legend: {
      layout: 'proximate',
      align: 'right'
    },


    title: {
      floating: true,
      align: 'left',
      x: 93,
      y: 20,
      text: 'Confirmed cases per country per 1000 inhabitants'
    },
    subtitle: {
      floating: true,
      align: 'left',
      y: 60,
      x: 90,
      text:  ' Заработано: ' + globalData[0].data[0][1],
      style: {
        fontSize: '20px'
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      split: true,
      pointFormatter: function() {
        <!-- var value = format(this.y); -->
        <!-- return `<span style="color:${this.color}">●</span> ${this.series.name}: <b>${value}</b><br/>`; -->
            }
    },

    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: ''
      },
      maxPadding: 0.2,
      softMax: 1
    },

    xAxis: {

      gridLineWidth: 2,
      min: globalData[0].data[0][0],
      minRange: 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,
      type: 'datetime'
      <!-- categories: [1] -->
    },


    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        animation: {
          duration
        },
        <!-- marker: { -->
          <!-- symbol: 'circle' -->
        <!-- }, -->
        dataLabels: {
          formatter: function() {
            return format(this.y);
          }
        }
      }
    },
    series: globalData.map(series => {
      return {
        name: series.name,
        data: series.data.slice(0, startIterator).map(point => {
                    return { x: point[0], y: point[1] }
                })
      }
    })
  });
}


function getCountryPopulation(country) {
  return {
    "Заработано": 1,
    "Финансовый результат": 1
  }[country];
}
```

Product version Highcharts JS v10.3.2 (2022-11-28)

It is necessary to skip days on the X axis that are not in the JSON file. need: 2022-5-30 2022-5-31 2022-6-1 2022-6-2 2022-6-3 2022-6-6

I don't need to filter JSON. The JSON file just indicates what I need, but the script itself substitutes dates that are not in JSON.

Be careful, dates are skipped in JSON, and the library inserts missing dates. I need only those dates that are specified in JSON, it can be weekends or two days a week.

Comment: Hi @Ринат Ауди, I am not sure what exactly you want to achieve. You can use categories instead of dates, but there will not be enough space to show all of them. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/01o7eaxt/

Comment: Thanks. But that's not what I need. Your script skips weekends, and I need it to take into account all the dates that are in JSON. Look at the graph that your script draws.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand. If you show all dates from the JSON as x-axis labels, all of the labels will be unreadable, for example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/03sdxa8q/

Comment: dates will be grouped in the library. The main thing for me is to display them and only those that are specified.

Comment: In the last example, all specified dates are displayed. Could you add more detals about what is wrong there?

Comment: https://skr.sh/sIUNuXOi35m this date is not in the json file. and on the X-axis it is.You need to make sure that it is not displayed.

Comment: Here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/03sdxa8q/ every date from the json is shown. It is better visible in an example with a smaller amount of data: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7qdyb9vj/

Comment: add category to xAxis, but now my dates are displayed in UNIXTIME and they are not compressed as it was before. 
https://yofa.ru/index2.html  Here. I wanted the same, only without dates, which are not in json. And the dates disappear as they fill in.

https://yofa.ru/index3.html  And here I added category instead of datetime, and the unixtime format began to be displayed

Comment: I updated your example with several small corrections: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bav1prxc/ As an alternative you can check Highstock chart type with oridinal x-axis: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/getting-started-stock

Comment: Wow. To the point. Thank you, this is what I was looking for!!!